# Entity Framework see SQL sentence when calling stored procedure

Tags: entity-framework

Is there a way to see the underlying SQL sentence when executing a stored procedure in Entity Framework (3.5)?

To use the stored procedure I did from the diagram: Add, Function Import… etc

Thanks

**UPDATE 1**
I downloaded 'AnjLab Sql Profiler' from.

http://code.google.com/p/sqlexpressprofiler/downloads/list

And was able to see that the stored procedure is executed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any type of database profiler - for example SQL profiler for SQL server or you can use either [EFTracingProvider](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/EFProviderWrappers) or any EF profiler (these tools are usually commercial). [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg490349.aspx) is whole article about these techniques.